# why there is 'by' for the extended class and reified in function define

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

coming across a sample with a class and a function and trying to understand the koltin syntax there,

1. what does this `IMeta by dataItem`  do?  looked at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#classes and dont see how to use `by` in the derived class
2. why the `reified`  is required in the `inline fun <reified T> getDataItem()`?  If someone could give a sample to explain the `reified`?

   ```
   class DerivedStreamItem(private val dataItem: IMeta, private val dataType: String?) :
       IMeta by dataItem {

   override fun getType(): String = dataType ?: dataItem.getType()
   fun getData(): DerivedData? = getDataItem()

   private inline fun <reified T> getDataItem(): T? = if (dataItem is T) dataItem else null
   ```

   }

for the reference, copied the related defines here:

```
interface IMeta {
    fun getType() : String
    fun getUUIDId() : String
    fun getDataId(): String?
}

class DerivedData : IMeta {
    override fun getType(): String {
        return ""  // stub
    }

    override fun getUUIDId(): String {
        return ""  // stub
    }

    override fun getDataId(): String? {
        return ""  // stub
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#type-erasure-and-generic-type-checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the `reified` is required in the `inline fun <reified T> getDataItem()`? If someone could give a sample to explain the reified?

There is some good [documentation on reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), but I'll try to boil it down a bit.

The `reified` keyword in Kotlin is used to get around the fact that the JVM uses type erasure for generic. That means at runtime whenever you refer to a generic type, the JVM has *no* idea what the actual type is. It is a compile-time thing only. So that `T` in your example... the JVM has no idea what it means (without reification, which I'll explain).

You'll notice in your example that you are also using the `inline` keyword. That tells Kotlin that rather than call a function when you reference it, to just insert the body of the function `inline`. This can be more efficient in certain situations. So, if Kotlin is already going to be copying the body of our function at compile time, why not just copy the class that `T` represents as well? This is where `reified` is used. This tells Kotlin to refer to the actual concrete type of `T`, and only works with `inline` functions.

If you were to remove the `reified` keyword from your example, you would get an error: "Cannot check for instance of erased type: T". By reifying this, Kotlin knows what actual type `T` is, letting us do this comparison (and the resulting smart cast) safely.

Answer (score 2):

(Since you are asking two questions, I'm going to answer them separately)

The `by` keyword in Kolin is used for delegation. There are two kinds of delegation:

1) [Implementation by Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation) (sometimes called Class Delegation)

This allows you to implement an interface and delegate calls to that interface to a concrete object. This is helpful if you want to extend an interface but not implement every single part of it. For example, we can extend `List` by delegating to it, and allowing our caller to give us an implementation of `List`

```
class ExtendedList(someList: List) : List by someList {
   // Override anything from List that you need
   // All other calls that would resolve to the List interface are 
   // delegated to someList   
}
```

2) [Property Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)

This allows you to do similar work, but with properties. My favorite example is `lazy`, which lets you lazily define a property. Nothing is created until you reference the property, and the result is cached for quicker access in the future.

From the Kotlin documentation:

```
val lazyValue: String by lazy {
    println("computed!")
    "Hello"
}
```

Comment: thx! do not know use 'by' for the implementation of a passing param, great!